# Не добавляются данные из-за id

Tags: php, mysql

```
в mysql добавляю запись в таблице их немного их id 845, 876, 878, через форму добавляет запись с таким числом 2147483647 и все, больше не идет, как начать его счет относительно сначала?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

сбросить счетчик:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT =879
```

Comment: да именно так и сделал)